# Meteor.jd, realtime latency with complex pusblish/subscribe rules?

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing, meteor, real-time

I'm playing with realtime whiteboards with meteor. My first attempt was working very well, if you open 2 browsers and draw in one of them, the other one updates in a few milliseconds ( http://pen.meteor.com/stackoverflow )

Now, my second project, is to make an infinite realtime whiteboard. The main thing that changes now, is that all lines are grouped by zones, and the viewer only subscribe to the lines in the visible zones. And now there is a dealy of 5 seconds (!) when you do something in   one browser to see it happen in the other one ( http://carve.meteor.com/love ).

I've tried to add indexes in the mongo database for the fields determining the zones.
I've tried updating the Collection only for a full line (and not each time I push a new point like i my first project).
I've tried adding a timeout not to subscribe too often when scrolling or zooming the board.

Nothing changes, always a 5 seconds delay.

I don't have this delay when working locally.

Here is the piece of code responsible for subscribing to the lines you the visible area :

```
subscribeTimeout=false;

Deps.autorun(function () {
    var vT=Session.get("visible_tiles");
    var board_key=Session.get("board_key");
    if (subscribeTimeout) Meteor.clearTimeout(subscribeTimeout);
    subscribeTimeout=Meteor.setTimeout(subscribeLines, 500);
});
function subscribeLines() {
    subscribeTimeout=false;
    var vT=Session.get("visible_tiles");
    console.log("SUBSCRIBE");
    Meteor.subscribe("board_lines", Session.get("board_key"),vT.left,vT.right,vT.top,vT.bottom, function() {
        console.log("subscribe board_lines "+Session.get("board_key"));
    });
}
```

Comment: I see a much bigger delay than 5 seconds there. I have a similar application with meteor that behaves almost the same. I've built a chat application and it's not very "real time". Let me know what you found out.

Answer (score 1):

I've been a SysAdmin for 15 years. Without running the code, it sounds like an imposed limitation of the meteor.com server. They probably put in delays on the resources so everyone gets a fair share. I'd publish to another server like heroku for an easy deploy or manually to another server like linode or my favorite Joyent. Alternatively you could try and contact meteor.com directly and ask them if/how they limit resource usage.

Since the code runs fast/instantly locally, you should see sub-second response times from a good server over a good network.

Comment: Thank you Michael, I'll ask.